AWS Assume role and test on root user on linux
I try to create with certbot a new certificate with route53 plugin and dns01 challenge; but when i lunch
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/EC2CertbotRole --role-session-name "blah"
i can retrive my hosted zones if i don't use sudo command.
for create certificate i needed sudo permission and the aws role and i try lunch the command with -E parameter for use the same enviroment of no root use.
i just tried to lunch assume role command in root use with sudo su, but it's doesen't work
